# Find tables like a given name and run query against each

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with tables that have an `epochdate` appended to their names and I need to run a query against all tables for a given date.

e.g.

```
Logons[epochdate1]
Logons[epochdate2]
Logons[epochdate3]
```

The query

```
SELECT COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'eventlog'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Logons106236%'
```

Could return 2 or 3 tables for a given day which I then want to do [pseudocode]:

```
foreach (table in tables) {
    insert into temptable(
        select logonid, logontime, logontype
        from table
        where logontype = 10)
}
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sp_executesql` to run a query in a string, and modify this sort of approach to your needs.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY, ObjectId INT);

INSERT INTO @t SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables;

DECLARE @r AS INT = @@rowcount, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(ObjectId)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(ObjectId))
    FROM @t 
    WHERE Id = @r;

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SET @r = @r - 1;
END
```

You can also use `sp_executesql` with an INSERT like this:

```
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (object_id INT, [name] NVARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO @t2
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT object_id, name FROM sys.tables';

SELECT * FROM @t2;
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks Stewart!